# Block (or strip out) FlowFile Content

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to perform an HTTP Post from NiFi, but I don't want/need the request to carry all of the FlowFile's content.

Is there some way to pass *attributes* of a FlowFile but **not** the full content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request body of your Http Post is JSON, you can use the [AttributesToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/index.html) Processor which allows you to pick which attributes you want to include in the resulting JSON. You can then configure the processor so the resulting JSON overwrites the existing flowfile content.

Keep in mind that the resulting JSON will be flat so you may need to transform it to the expected format. For that, you can use the [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) Processor.

Below is an example of what your dataflow might look like. I hope this helps!

[image]